# Get value from emberjs form

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm a newbie with Emberjs and I need some advices.

I try to use this addon https://github.com/indexiatech/ember-forms

So I have created my form :

```
 {{#em-form model=sessions submit_button=false}}
    {{em-input property="email" type=email label="Email" placeholder="Entrer votre email..."}}
    {{em-input property="password" type="password" label="Mot de passe" placeholder="Enter votre password..."}}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input {{bind-attr disabled=isntValid}} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Se connecter">
    </div>
 {{/em-form}}
```

so I have a controller to catch the submit action :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 actions: {
  submit: function(){
   alert(this.get('sessions.email'));
  }
 }
});
```

My question is just I don't get it to how print my value from my form? I try `this.get('email')` or `this.get('sessions.email')` but always got an `undefined` in my alert box

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an action from the form

```
{{#em-form model=sessions submit_button=false action='foo'}}
    ...
{{/em-form}}
```

and then catch the action in the controller

```
actions: {
  foo: function() {
    console.log(this.get('email'))
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked in ember but with handlebars/ember should it not be `{{#em-form model=sessions submit_button=false action "foo"}} // not action="foo" ` not sure if that makes a difference but it's worth a try @Kaëris

Comment: no you can't in my logs I have this msg `Expecting 'EQUALS', got 'STRING'`, but thanks for trying to help :)